# localhost:27017: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $in needs an array one To Many Relation in Symfony2 and MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I have a collection called wings. I have a one to many relationship for classes for each wing. For one wing there are multiple classes.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("53db122b0cd7e32d148b4567"),
    "name": "Senior",
    "tenant": {
        "$ref": "Tenant",
        "$id": ObjectId("53887e53dda3aaac0600003b"),
        "$db": "mydbName"
    },
    "classes": {
        "0": {
            "$ref": "StudentClass",
            "$id": ObjectId("538c5cd9dda3aae409000029"),
            "$db": "eduboldyps"
        },
        "1":{
            "$ref": "StudentClass",
            "$id": ObjectId("538c5cd9dda3aae40900002b"),
            "$db": "eduboldyps"
        }  
    }
}
```

So when I am fetching data in my controller like following:

```
$allWingsArray = array();

foreach($documents as $wings){
    $innerWingsArrays = array();
    $innerWingsArrays['name'] = $wings->getId();
    $innerWingsArrays['name'] = $wings->getName();

    //Get all Assigned wigns for each wing here
    foreach($wings->getclasses() as $clss) {
        $arrayclassess = array_values($clss);

        //Herer I am getting Error
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($arrayclassess);
    }

    $allWingsArray[] = $innerWingsArrays;
}
```

So while fetching classes which are multiple relationship I am getting following error:

`localhost:27017: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $in needs an array`
I am using MONGODB Version 2.6.11 and Symfony 2.3.7
Any help will be appreciated, how to fix this. thanks in advance